# How can I write a generic equality comparison that will fall back to operator== when std::cmp_equal won't compile?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++20, customization-point

I want a generic equality-checking function that prefers to use std::cmp_equal when possible because of its virtues, but will use operator== for types that std::cmp_equal can't handle, such as bool or user-defined types.

This seemed like it should be an easy job for `requires`, but I was surprised to discover that although this works for libc++, it fails for libstdc++ with static_assert messages.

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T, typename U>
auto generic_equal(T t, U u) {
    if constexpr (requires { std::cmp_equal(t, u); }) {
        return std::cmp_equal(t, u);
    } else {
        return t == u;
    }
}

struct A {
    friend bool operator==(A,A) = default;
};

int main() {
    generic_equal(false, false);
    generic_equal(-1, 5);
    generic_equal(A{}, A{});
}
```

Is there a good way to convince the compiler to realize it can't instantiate std::cmp_equal at the `requires` instead of at the call?

Compiler explorer link showing success with libc++ and failure with libstdc++: https://godbolt.org/z/nKzfE87Ye

Comment: hmm, probably nothing better than `if constexpr (can_cmp_equal<T> && can_cmp_equal<U>)` with `template <typename T> constexpr bool can_cmp_equal = std::is_integral_v<T>;  template <> constexpr bool can_cmp_equal<bool> = false;` 
And maybe just report an error to gcc bugzilla https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::cmp_equal`](https://eel.is/c++draft/utility.intcmp) requires that the template parameter must be of *standard integer types* or *extended integer types*, which is defined in [[basic.fundamental]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#def:type,extended_signed_integer):

> 1. There are five *standard signed integer types*: “`signed char`”, “`short int`”, “`int`”, “`long int`”, and “`long long int`”. In this list, each type provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list.
>    There may also be implementation-defined *extended signed integer types*. [...]
> 2. For each of the standard signed integer types, there exists a
>    corresponding (but different) *standard unsigned integer type*:
>    “`unsigned char`”, “`unsigned short int`”, “`unsigned int`”,
>    “`unsigned long int`”, and “`unsigned long long int`”. Likewise, for
>    each of the extended signed integer types, there exists a
>    corresponding *extended unsigned integer type*. [...]

Since it is not a constrained function, it will still be instantiated and hit internal possible static assertions when passed a non-standard integer type. You can determine whether to use `std::cmp_equal` for comparison by detecting whether the `T` is a *standard integer type*:

```
#include <utility>
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
concept standard_integral = 
  std::integral<T> &&
  !std::same_as<T, char> &&
  !std::same_as<T, char8_t> &&
  !std::same_as<T, char16_t> &&
  !std::same_as<T, char32_t> &&
  !std::same_as<T, wchar_t> &&
  !std::same_as<T, bool>;

template <typename T, std::equality_comparable_with<T> U>
bool generic_equal(T t, U u) {
    if constexpr (standard_integral<T> && standard_integral<U>) {
        return std::cmp_equal(t, u);
    } else {
        return t == u;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alas, this approach won't handle whatever extended integer types std::cmp_equal might support on a particular implementation.  I had hoped to avoid writing a list of supported types at all.

Comment: @KyleMarkley : Why would `cmp_equal` support a different set of types than `is_integral`?

Comment: @ildjarn std::cmp_* specifically exclude a few types that may hold numbers but that aren't numeric in nature, like char.

Comment: Upon reflection, this approach does work, because is_integral covers both the standard integer types and the extended integer types.  I erroneously thought it wouldn't because they're "extended" (== "not standard").